# Converting rows from a table into days of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I thought was going to be a fairly easy task is becoming a lot more difficult than I expected.  We have several tasks that get performed sometimes several times per day, so we have a table that gets a row added whenever a user performs the task.  What I need is a snapshot of the month with the initials and time of the person that did the task like this:

[image: Snapshot]

The 'activity log' table is pretty simple, it just has the date/time the task was performed along with the user that did it and the scheduled time (the "Pass Time" column in the image); this is the table I need to flatten out into days of the week.

Each 'order' can have one or more 'pass times' and each pass time can have zero or more initials for that day.  For example, for pass time 8:00, it can be done several times during that day or not at all.

I have tried standard joins to get the orders and the scheduled pass times with no issues, but getting the days of the week is escaping me.  I have tried creating a function to get all the initials for the day and just creating

'select FuncCall() as [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeESV.png), FuncCall() as [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uGKc.png)', etc. for each day of the week but that is a real performance suck.

Does anyone know of a better technique?

Update:  I think the comment about PIVOT looks promising, but not quite sure because everything I can find uses an aggregate function in the PIVOT part.  So if I have the following table:

```
create table #MyTable (OrderName nvarchar(10),DateDone date, TimeDone time, Initials nvarchar(4), PassTime nvarchar(8))

insert into #MyTable values('Order 1','2018/6/1','2:00','ABC','1st Pass')
insert into #MyTable values('Order 1','2018/6/1','2:20','DEF','1st Pass')
insert into #MyTable values('Order 1','2018/6/1','4:40','XYZ','2nd Pass')
insert into #MyTable values('Order 1','2018/6/3','5:00','ABC','1st Pass')
insert into #MyTable values('Order 1','2018/6/4','4:00','QXY','2nd Pass')
insert into #MyTable values('Order 1','2018/6/10','2:00','ABC','1st Pass')

select * from #MyTable

pivot ()  -- Can't figure out what goes here since all examples I see have an aggregate function call such as AVG...

drop table #MyTable
```

I don't see how to get this output since I am not aggregating anything other than the initials column:
[image]

Comment: can you provides us sample data as formatted text for each tables. And the desired output.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want DATEPART ( dw , yourdate)? Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Along with DATEPART as mentioned by @GeorgeMenoutis, You also need [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) to get data in mentioned format.

Comment: You might look into CROSS APPLY VALUES as a way to unpivot your data.

Comment: Yes, I can use DatePart to get the day of the week, but the problem is how to efficiently get the initials for each day without doing a function call?

Comment: Thanks for the Pivot suggestion, I think it may work if I can get past the requirement for an aggregate function call; I updated my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @taskTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Task VARCHAR(100),TaskPerson VARCHAR(100),TaskDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @taskTable VALUES
 ('Task before June 2018','AB','2018-05-15T12:00:00')
,('Task 1','AB','2018-06-03T13:00:00')
,('Task 1','CD','2018-06-04T14:00:00')
,('Task 2','AB','2018-06-05T15:00:00')
,('Task 1','CD','2018-06-06T16:00:00')
,('Task 1','EF','2018-06-06T17:00:00')
,('Task 1','EF','2018-06-06T18:00:00')
,('Task 2','GH','2018-06-07T19:00:00')
,('Task 1','CD','2018-06-07T20:00:00')
,('After June 2018','CD','2018-07-15T21:00:00');

SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT t.Task
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Task,CAST(t.TaskDate AS DATE) ORDER BY t.TaskDate) AS Taskindex
          ,CONCAT(t.TaskPerson,' ',CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),t.TaskDate,114)) AS Content
          ,DAY(TaskDate) AS ColumnName
    FROM @taskTable t
    WHERE YEAR(t.TaskDate)=2018 AND MONTH(t.TaskDate)=6
) tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Content) FOR ColumnName IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]
                                  ,[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20]
                                  ,[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31])
) P
ORDER BY P.Task,Taskindex;
```

The result

```
+--------+-----------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Task   | Taskindex | 1    | 2    | 3        | 4        | 5        | 6        | 7        | 8    | 9    | 10   | 11   | 12   | 13   | 14   | 15   | 16   | 17   | 18   | 19   | 20   | 21   | 22   | 23   | 24   | 25   | 26   | 27   | 28   | 29   | 30   | 31   |
+--------+-----------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Task 1 | 1         | NULL | NULL | AB 13:00 | CD 14:00 | NULL     | CD 16:00 | CD 20:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+--------+-----------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Task 1 | 2         | NULL | NULL | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | EF 17:00 | NULL     | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+--------+-----------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Task 1 | 3         | NULL | NULL | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | EF 18:00 | NULL     | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+--------+-----------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Task 2 | 1         | NULL | NULL | NULL     | NULL     | AB 15:00 | NULL     | GH 19:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+--------+-----------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

The first trick is, to use the day's index (`DAY()`) as column name. The second trick is the `ROW_NUMBER()`. This will add a running index per task and day thus replicating the rows per index. Otherwise you'd get just one entry per day.

You input tables will be more complex, but I think this shows the principles...

### UPDATE: So we have to get it even slicker :-D

```
WITH prepareData AS
(
    SELECT t.Task
          ,t.TaskPerson
          ,t.TaskDate
          ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t.TaskDate,126) AS TaskDay
          ,DAY(t.TaskDate) AS TaskDayIndex
          ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),t.TaskDate,114) AS TimeContent
    FROM @taskTable t
    WHERE YEAR(t.TaskDate)=2018 AND MONTH(t.TaskDate)=6
)
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT t.Task
          ,STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + CONCAT(x.TaskPerson,' ',TimeContent)
            FROM prepareData AS x
            WHERE x.Task=t.Task
              AND x.TaskDay= t.TaskDay
            ORDER BY x.TaskDate
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
           ).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') AS Content
          ,t.TaskDayIndex
    FROM prepareData t
    GROUP BY t.Task, t.TaskDay,t.TaskDayIndex
) p--tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Content) FOR TaskDayIndex IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]
                                    ,[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20]
                                    ,[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31])
) P
ORDER BY P.Task;
```

The result

```
+--------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+------------------------------+----------+------+
| Task   | 1    | 2    | 3        | 4        | 5        | 6                            | 7        | 8    |
+--------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+------------------------------+----------+------+
| Task 1 | NULL | NULL | AB 13:00 | CD 14:00 | NULL     | CD 16:00, EF 17:00, EF 18:00 | CD 20:00 | NULL |
+--------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+------------------------------+----------+------+
| Task 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL     | NULL     | AB 15:00 | NULL                         | GH 19:00 | NULL |
+--------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+------------------------------+----------+------+
```

This will use a well discussed XML trick within a correlated sub-query in order to get all common entries together as one. With this united content you can go the normal `PIVOT` path. The aggregate will not compute anything, as there is - for sure - just one value per cell.

Comment: That's pretty damn slick, Thanks!   I have been playing with it to see if I can get just one 'Task 1' but I can't seem to roll them up.  It looks like the ROW_NUMBER keeps forcing a new line for each Taskindex.  So day 6 in your example would have only 1 'Task 1' row with 3 initials concatenated together.  I can take that ROW_NUMBER line out and I do get just one 'Task 1' line but it only has the first set of initials for day 6...?

Comment: Damn, you are right, that is even slicker :)  I need to study this

Comment: I'm getting a better understanding of it, @Shnugo.  One thing is got me stuck and that is that each task belongs to a parent; for example, in my update above, notice the "Order 1" column; that is the parent and each parent will have multiple tasks, so in your example, 'Task 1', 'Task 2', etc., will each belong to a particular order (parent).  I have tried adding in the 'parent' column to the top select and bottom group by and no joy.  So in my screenshot above, 'Order 1' will have some tasks and so will 'Order 2', and so on...

Comment: @user197505 You are doing something [which is called *chameleon question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/311071). Your screenshot does not show any Order 2... What you should do: Close this question by accepting it (pays points to both of us), vote (if not done yet) and start a new question. Use my code to establish a [stand-alone MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), provide consumable data and the expected output (no pictures!). Than place a link here and wait for the helping armada of SO.

Comment: You are right, and by pulling out my mcve, I think I was able to find what I was doing wrong; I created a 'ParentTask' column and grouped by that and it is looking good.   If you post your email (or get it to me someway), I will send you an Amazon gift card; that was a ton of help!

Comment: @user197505 Always glad to help! My eMail is a bit hidden in my profile, but I'd prefer if you'd place a donation to any organisation helping children. A ton of help for them is the better gift :-D